# JavaScript [ ].sort( ) method sorts when it should leave elements alone

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects in JavaScript.  I would like to sort them by a particular metric.  It so happens in a special case that the metric has the same value every time.  Here is an example array:

```
var myArray = [{"key":400686,"metric":999999},{"key":52601288,"metric":999999},{"key":1380180030,"metric":999999},{"key":909661,"metric":999999},{"key":401336,"metric":999999},{"key":1317275,"metric":999999},{"key":8642696,"metric":999999},{"key":1374360020,"metric":999999},{"key":602871933,"metric":999999},{"key":410174,"metric":999999},{"key":503411,"metric":999999},{"key":401511,"metric":999999},{"key":410196,"metric":999999},{"key":419377,"metric":999999},{"key":429167,"metric":999999},{"key":609656,"metric":999999},{"key":837941,"metric":999999},{"key":2410791,"metric":999999},{"key":4501004,"metric":999999},{"key":8633371,"metric":999999},{"key":1356540155,"metric":999999},{"key":1374360757,"metric":999999}];
```

When I make something as simple as this call:

```
myArray.sort( function( a, b ){ return 0; } );
```

The array gets sorted!  It should obviously be left alone since a return value of 0 in the sort function indicates equality.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because the sort is *unstable*, it doesn't necessarily preserve the relative order of equal items.

You can use a [stable sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) algorithm, like [merge sort](http://en.literateprograms.org/Merge_sort_%28JavaScript%29).

Answer (score 4):

0 indicates equality, which implies that the elements are interchangeable. It doesn't imply that they won't be moved around. It implies that they are free to be swapped or remain where they are and the array will still be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want identical elements to be sorted into a predictable order, then you need a secondary key that lets you identify which identical element should be before the other.  In your example array, you could use a custom sort function like this that would sort first by metric and, if those were identical, then by key:

```
myArray.sort( function( a, b ){ 
    if (a.metric != b.metric) {
        return(b.metric - a.metric);
    }
    // when metrics are the same, sort by key as secondary sort
    return(b.key - a.key)
});
```

Or, if you want to preserve the existing order for identical elements, then you need a quick pass to add an order value each time before you sort:

```
// mark each value with it's current position in the array
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i].sortIndexForTies = i;
}
myArray.sort( function( a, b ){ 
    if (a.metric != b.metric) {
        return(b.metric - a.metric);
    }
    // when metrics are the same, sort by the original array position as second sort key
    return(b.sortIndexForTies - a.sortIndexForTies)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice workaround where I bias the sorting by adding a delta on the sorted parameter outside the precision I care about on that parameter.  The bias makes the array tend to stay in the same order.  If there is a single unit of difference in the distance (my precision is in the 1s place) that element gets properly sorted.

```
for( var i = 0, len = myArray.length, delta = 0; i < len; i++, delta += 0.000001 )
{
  myArray[ i ].metric -= delta;
}

function byMetric( a, b )
{
  return b.metric - a.metric;
}

myArray.sort( byMetric );
```